# routing issue when redirecting from aspx to cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to redirect my old site pages aspx to my new site pages in mvc 4(cshtml) using routing and I added this code in Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Contact",
    url: "Contact.aspx",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Contact", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

it is working fine but every time after post action it shows Contact.aspx instead of /Home/Contact What should I do for this?

When I fill the form of Contact us.and its post action it shows Contact.aspx in address bar

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect permanently instead of attempting to do routing. Here's a [`nice blog post`](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/04/aspnet-mvc---legacy-url-routing.aspx) which illustrates how to write a custom route that will perform the redirect.